# Reason for certain steps in Circuit Analysis

Tags: analog, circuit-analysis

[image]

The image is from [this](http://www.ee.iitm.ac.in/~nagendra/shanthi_lectures/EC201/02AugEC201/Aug2EC201.html) lecture.The instructor Prof. Shanthi Pavan says that the part encircled in orange can be replaced by a voltage source with current through \$v_1\$ as \$i_1\$ and not \$i_1 + I_1\$ as shown in the next figure:

[image]

Then he does this for all the branches as shown here:
[image]

Please help me by providing an explanation.I'm not able to figure out why the above mentioned thing could be done.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3):

Your professors analysis and lecture is very good.  Your question above is out of context and as such you've really kneecapped anyone who is going to analyze it without them understanding that this is really just part of an analysis and rationale for how you do small signal analysis.  He is taking you through replacing the non-linear elements and substituting in the small signal equivalents (all lower case letters as is the convention).

I would recommend going back to ~ 18 minute mark and listening carefully.

He has removed the large signal currents (capital letters above - as is the convention) because they represent the operating point (or network bias).  When you are doing small signal analysis you don't consider those currents you only care about the incremental (small signal) currents and voltages.  His approach is a more rigorous (i.e. proper) derivation.

Comment: First of all THANKS A TON for actually watching it and replying.



I didn't understand the derivation.Till the point where he adds the additional current source(in red colour) is clear.

This way he's converting it to a problem on networks.Next, I couldn't follow his reasoning for replacing that part by a voltage source.
I tried listening to it numerous times.
(He says the the current \$I_1\$ goes in a loop and then he's removing it.)

That is exactly the point I couldn't follow.

Comment: On SE we say thank you by upvoting and/or accepting.

Comment: I'm sorry for the incomplete context. I assumed that as the whole problem has been converted to a problem on networks,the details I gave would be sufficient.

Comment: Upvoted.I still have a doubt about that point.

Comment: In small signal analysis you remove biases and replace voltage sources with grounds etc. it's a subtle argument in the lecture, do pay attention to it as it's important.